# Italic support for CJK language in IText 7

Tags: java, itext, rtf, itext7

I want to create PDF out of RTF content where CJK language text are in Italic. When I create PDF using Itext libraries fonts are not coming up as "Italic".

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. If you post the problematic code line - we could help better!

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p><em><span style="font-size: 18.0pt; line-height: 107%; font-family: PMingLiU, serif; color: #ba4b4b; border: none windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0in;">测试</span><span style="font-size: 18.0pt; line-height: 107%; font-family: Cambria, serif; color: #ba4b4b; border: none windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0in;">&nbsp;</span></em></p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream ios=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile("itextkey1543224277255_0.xml");
  File htmlSource = new File("PDFInput.html");
  File file = new File(TARGET);
  ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
  FontProvider dfp = new DefaultFontProvider(true, false, false);  
  dfp.addFont("fonts/NotoKufiArabic-hinted/NotoKufiArabic-Bold.ttf");
  dfp.addFont("fonts/NotoKufiArabic-hinted/NotoKufiArabic-Regular.ttf");

Comment: dfp.addFont("fonts/NotoSansCJKsc-hinted/NotoSansCJKsc-Bold.otf");
  dfp.addFont("fonts/NotoSansCJKsc-hinted/NotoSansCJKsc-Regular.otf");
  dfp.addFont("fonts/NotoSansCJKtc-hinted/NotoSansCJKtc-Bold.otf");
  dfp.addFont("fonts/NotoSansCJKtc-hinted/NotoSansCJKtc-Regular.otf");
  converterProperties.setFontProvider(dfp);
  PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(ios);
  PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
  pdf.setDefaultPageSize(pageSize);  
  HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(htmlSource), pdf, converterProperties);

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to be able to ask questions of higher quality